# PHP Send HTML Form Data to MySQL + An External URL

Tags: php, forms

My objective is to send the data that is submitted in a html form to both a mysql database (already accomplished) and also to an external URL. The reason for sending to the url as well is to add the data to a automated dialler system for our call center.

The problem I have is I can't get my head around once the information is sent to the database, how to then send to a url, I currently have my PHP page send data to mysql and THEN to an email address.

An example of the url:

```
http://domain.com/vicidial/non_agent_api.php?source=test&user=****&pass=****&function=add_lead&phone_number=07777777777
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cURL to send HTTP request to certain url.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://domain.com/vicidial/non_agent_api.php?source=test&user=****&pass=****&function=add_lead&phone_number=07777777777");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Cant say for sure if above snippet works, because I dont have PHP devenviroment right now, but that should be the basic idea to be able to send data to another url.

More help: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: thought that would work but I got an error, i think it was something to do with having that code plus sending the user to a thank you page? here is the error:
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

Comment: Do you use php header()-function?

The error may come from that the PHP have already outputted data.
Do you have any prints or echos in your script?

Comment: Do you have any html, prints or echos etc. Before that?

Comment: Does the CURL part work? Can you remove the header() part and test that if CURL works. I have read that error: Cannot modify header information could come also from cURL, from php safe_mode or basedir settings to be exact.